# approximate nearest neighbor library for python (WINDOWS)

Tags: python, matplotlib

My main intention is just use some functions in the ann library in Pylab to calculate nearest neighbor.
My system is Windows Vista 32 bit. I have a few questions about the [ANN webpage](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/).

1. For ANN Version 1.1.2, I found two download options "ann_1.1.2.zip" and "ann_1.1.2_MS_Win32_bin.zip" for Windows. After reading the ANN manual, I believe "ann_1.1.2.zip" needs to compiling on Microsoft Windows Systems. And "ann_1.1.2_MS_Win32_bin.zip" is the precompiled Files for Microsoft Windows. I have no idea which one should I download since I don't know their difference.
2. Actually I downloaded "ann_1.1.2_MS_Win32_bin.zip" and I found some library file and dll file. What should I do with them if I want to use ann library in pylab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [scikits.ann](http://projects.scipy.org/scikits/wiki/AnnWrapper) ([Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.ann)).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've got some real difficulty in using ANN with Pylab.

The website contains C++ code and precompiled libraries. This is nice of them, as not all Windows users have C++ compilers available. However, *calling* into a library requires some sort of programming environment.

To call into C++ code from Python will require writing some [language bindings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding), often using a tool such as [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) or [SIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP_%28software%29) to help automate the work. Preparing bindings is *not* a trivial task, though it provides an excellent opportunity to learn about the interpreter internals of your language of choice. If you're lucky, someone else has already done this work for you. However, I don't see any such bindings packaged for Ubuntu and their main page did not list any bindings. (Ubuntu *does* have ANN-bindings for [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), which might be useful to you if you're familiar enough with Octave to get your work done there.)